# How can I set a tooltip to display while dragging an NSSlider?

Tags: cocoa, tooltip, nsslider

I've got an NSSlider. I've set it to update continuously. In my update code I have:

```
  [quality setToolTip:qualityTooltips[pos]];
```

This updates the tooltip, but the tooltip is not displayed while I'm dragging the slider. In fact it vanishes as soon as you click the slider. I'd like it to always be visible while I'm dragging the slider, is this possible?